# Set RegEx in Java to be non-greedy by default

Tags: java, regex, string

I have Strings like the following:

```
"parameter: param0=true, param1=401230 param2=asset client: desktop"
"parameter: param0=false, param1=15230 user: user213 client: desktop"
"parameter: param0=false, param1=51235 param2=asset result: ERROR"
```

The pattern is `parameter:`, then the `param`'s, and after the params either `client:` and/or `user:` and/or `result`.

I want to match the stuff between `parameter:` and the first occurrence of either `client:`, `user:` or `result:`

So for the 2nd String it should match `param0=false, param1=15230`.

My regex is:

```
parameter:\s+(.*)\s+(result|client|user):
```

But now if I match the 2nd String it captures `param0=false, param1=15230 user: user213` (looks like regex is matching greedy)

1. How to fix this? `parameter:\s+(.*)\s+(result|client|user)+?:` won't fix it
2. With [this regex tester](http://regex101.com/) I can add the modifier `U` to the regex to make regex lazy by default, is this possible in Java too?

Comment: You can use `U` flag to use ungreedy or just concatenate `?` to your `*` and having `x*?` or `x+?`

Comment: @Fede There is no `(?U)` flag in Java.

Comment: @Unihedron oh good to know. There are so many engines and some many different features that I mess up. Thanks.

Comment: @Fede I posted a link to the Java Pattern documentation in my answer. You can also see [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting the `?` character inside the first captured group (the subpattern you intend to extract):

```
parameter:\\s+(.*?)\\s+(result|client|user):
```

Answer (score 5):

No. There is no ungreedy modifier in Java. You have to use `?` behind modifiers to make the quantifiers as lazy capture.

This means you should denote all quantifiers with a `?`, see the following pattern:

```
"parameter:\\s+?(.*?)\\s+?(result|client|user):"
```

> Specified by:
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html